# How to create timeout wrapper for unittest class

Tags: python-2.7, python-unittest

I am trying to create a timeout wrapper for a unittest class using this question as a template: 
[PyUnit - How to unit test a method that runs into an infinite loop for some input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366761/pyunit-how-to-unit-test-a-method-that-runs-into-an-infinite-loop-for-some-inpu)

The above solution works well if running from Main, but I'm trying to create a similar timeout by using a unittest class, but it fails.

*PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not found as TimeTest.test1*

I'm open to any other solutions that are platform independent and work with the native 2.7 library

Here is the code

```
import unittest
import multiprocessing as mp
import functools as ft
import time

def timeout(seconds=5, error_message="Timeout"):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            process = mp.Process(None, func, None, args, kwargs)
            process.start()
            process.join(seconds)
            if process.is_alive():
                process.terminate()
                raise mp.TimeoutError(error_message)

        return ft.wraps(func)(wrapper)
    return decorator

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 0

    @timeout(1)
    def test1(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.assertEquals(self.a, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the wrapper idea and creating a simple function and assert.

```
import unittest
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

TIME_LIMIT = 1

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 0

    def my_func(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.q.put(self.a + 1)

    def run_case(self, func):
        self.q = mp.Queue()

        test_process = mp.Process(target=func)

        test_process.start()
        test_process.join(TIME_LIMIT)

        self.assertFalse(test_process.is_alive(), 'timeout exceeded')

    def test_case1(self):
        self.run_case(self.my_func)
        self.assertEquals(self.a + 1, self.q.get())
```